# Woocommerce is it possible to disable quantity field on cart page, for some product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Basically, I finished building custom plugin for my client. 
the only thing after products added to cart, before the checkout.
 user able to change the quantity of the products, is it possible to display the selected quantity, but disabled the options to read only so client will able to see the quantity in cart page that he selected but can't change it?

and to apply this only to products that I used with my plugin either product ids or better category id because all the products there.
 other product display and able to change quantity regular 
by the way its regular products not virtual and not Sold Individually i need to find a way to limit clients to change quantity for some products only in cart page!, and not in product page.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: There's a filter for that [`woocommerce_cart_item_quantity`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/76b32c9aa52ebac70fe5a60a8d56351218760471/templates/cart/cart.php#L115)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use the woocommerce_cart_item_quantity filter for that. So that might look something like this:

```
function 668763_change_quantity_input( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    // whatever logic you want to determine whether or not to alter the input
    if ( $your_condition ) {
        return '<h3>' . $item['quantity'] . '</h3>';
    }

    return $product_quantity;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', '668763_change_quantity_input', 10, 3);
```

This would be just a simple example to replace the input with a h3 element containing the quantity. It can easily be adjust to alter the quantity input element to your liking.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i getting error 500 when using this, and want to disable it so user cannot able to change the quantity but to able to see it- in "$your_condition"  if  ( $product_id == 54) for example but, no luck and getting error 500

Comment: so i managed to do this by creating custom product type and then hiding field only from this product type  add_filter( 
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
            switch ( $product->product_type ) :
 case "my_photo":
  return true;                                                                                                                    but i noticed one small problem you can't select qty but it display that item have only 1 qty insted of 10  but the price is right, any way to fix this bug?

Comment: Hi Deez, I have run into a pickle. I found your code (above) and tried to replicate it with a condition of "if the quantity equals 0.1, display the H3 element" however everything I have tried doesn't seem to work. I currently have this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qbyhsosx/ , could you please let me know what I could do to make this work??